# Parse xml to object

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to convert my xml file to a list of objects.

```
private void ReadChangelog()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Changelog));
        Changelog changelog = (Changelog)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader("changelog.xml"));

        foreach (Release release in changelog.Releases)
        {
            string version = release.Version;
            string date = release.Date;
            string changes = release.Changes;
        }
    }
```

This is my changelog class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot()]
public class Changelog
{
    private Release[] releases;

    public Release[] Releases
    {
        get { return releases; }
        set { releases = value; }
    }
}

public class Release
{
    private string version;
    private string date;
    private string changes;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Version
    {
        get { return version; }
        set { version = value; }
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set { date = value; }
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Changes
    {
        get { return changes; }
        set { changes = value; }
    }
}
```

And this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Changelog>
  <Releases>
    <Release>
      <Version>1511</Version>
      <Date>25-11-2013</Date>
      <Changes>
        qzdqzdqzdqzdzdzzqefrsrgsrg
      </Changes>
    </Release>
    <Release>
      <Version>1510</Version>
      <Date>25-11-2013</Date>
      <Changes>
        Blabqzdzqdqzdqzd
      </Changes>
    </Release>
    <Release>
  </Releases>
</Changelog>
```

But when I try to run this I get an error

> InvalidOperationException, The xml document (1,1) contains an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try validating your XML 
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp ?

Comment: Does your last 'Release' need a closer?

Comment: You've used XmlAttribute to decorate the property, when the XML that you have is using "elements" to provide the Version, Date and Changes data. Either change your XML to put the data as "attributes" on the Release element, or change the way you define your Release class.

Answer (score 4):

`new StringReader("changelog.xml")` doesn't read in the contents of changelog.xml.  Instead, this code leaves you trying to deserialize the literal 'changelog.xml' string.  I think you want something like `new StreamReader("changelog.xml")`.

Answer (score 1):

`StringReader` creates `stream` from string content, not from the file with given path. User `StreamReader` instead.

```
Changelog changelog = (Changelog)serializer.Deserialize(new StreamReader("changelog.xml"));
```

Despite of that, there are couple more errors in your code:

1. Your document uses elements, and your class declaration uses `XmlAttributeAttribute`. It won't work together.
2. Your document is not a correct XML document. It has some elements that are not closed.